# Is progress kept between Regular and Gold Editions of Rainbow Six Siege?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

If I played until level 41 on a regular edition rainbow six siege cd, and want to sell the regular edition to get a gold edition cd, do I have to start all over again with level 1? Or all the progress is saved on the Xbox one hard drive and I'll continue from level 41?

As in do I get to continue with my progress if I get replacement cd?

Answer (score 1):

### You will not need to start over at level 1.

Assuming you use the same XBox Live account, your progress will carry over.  All of the operators that you unlocked will be available, and your level will still be 41.

I leveled up with the free edition over the weekend, and purchased the Advanced Edition yesterday.  All of my progress carried over, and I was granted the additional rewards of the Advanced Edition on my first login after purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Your progress is saved either on:

1. Your Ubisoft Account
2. Your Xbox/Playstation profile.

Changing which edition should keep your progress, however I'm unsure if it means you'll unlock operators or not properly as you may have to buy them if you had a starter edition for example etc.